# Visual Studio Detach Current Debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am working on a UWP application in Visual Studio 2015. I usually debug on desktop in x64, but today I debugged using ARM for a Windows phone (which worked fine). However, when I changed the architecture back to x64 to debug on desktop I got the error:

> A debugger is attached to ... but not configured to debug this unhandled exception. To debug this exception, detach the current debugger.

So it appears this is a rather common issue that is easily fixed by changing **debugger type** from **Managed only** to **Mixed**, but my project properties doesn't have any Debug options for changing debugger type. In fact, I don't see any debugger options in my project properties at all...

[image]

Am I looking in the wrong place here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find this setting under **Debug > Project_Name Properties > Debug**, it must have changed for VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2022 I found these settings in Debug >  Debug Properties (for both Packaged and Unpackaged), that solved the problem:

[image]

Edit:
This setting disabled Edit and Continue and Hot Reload.